# Internal server error in browser console when loading font.woff resource in Orchard cms

Tags: css, orchardcms

I use `Orchard CMS 1.10.1`. I have created a `font` folder inside `Content` folder in my custom theme. And put some font files in there.

And I use these files in a css file like this:

```
@font-face {
font-family: 'B-Yekan';
src: url(../Content/fonts/BYekan.eot) !important;
src: url(../Content/fonts/BYekan.otf), url(../Content/fonts/BYekan.woff) format('woff'), url(../Content/fonts/BYekan.ttf) format('truetype'), url(../Content/fonts/BYekan.svg#VitaminRegular) format('svg');
font-weight: normal;
font-style: normal;
}
```

But when website loads, I get some Internal server errors in browser's console like this:

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error)
http://localhost:30321/OrchardLocal/Themes/Eshoper/Content/fonts/BYekan.woff
```

What might be causing this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might need to check the following:

1. register your fonts mime types in web.config file, like this:

```xml
<system.webServer>
    <staticContent>
        <remove fileExtension=".woff" />
        <mimeMap fileExtension=".woff" mimeType="application/font-woff" />
    </staticContent>
</system.webServer>
```

This settings must be applied on `Orchard.Web/web.config`.

2. Check you`Content` folder if it contains a `web.config` file, with this configuration:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
        <staticContent>
            <clientCache cacheControlMode="UseMaxAge" cacheControlMaxAge="7.00:00:00" />
        </staticContent>
        <handlers accessPolicy="Script,Read">
            <!-- For any request to a file exists on disk, return it via native http module. AccessPolicy="Script" above is to allow for a managed 404 page. -->
            <add name="StaticFile" path="*" verb="*" modules="StaticFileModule" preCondition="integratedMode" resourceType="File" requireAccess="Read" />
        </handlers>
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

This file will tell Asp.Net that this folder contains static files, and this files will be handled by `StaticFileModule`.

Comment: Thanks for answer, I checked web.config file its already have this code. In my case problem might be something else.

Comment: Thanks again, yes I checked content folder it already had this file, but my font folder (which is inside Content folder) also had this file. I deleted web.config file inside the font folder and This solved the issue.

Comment: Thanks for this new useful info.

Comment: For my issue, it cause by the web.config file that has <mimeMap fileExtension=".woff" ...> statement on the static font folder. Delete it everything goes well. Also, I tried to add mimeMap statement on the website web.config file but cause the CSS loading error.